# ionic 2 upload image to django rest

Tags: django, http, django-rest-framework, ionic2

I am trying to upload an image from Ionic 2 app to Django-powered website through Django Rest API.

The API is working and tested through Postman but I always get HTTP 400 BAD Request error in Ionic.

Here is my code in Ionic:

```
openCamera(){
    var options = {
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    };
    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      this.imageName = imageData;
      this.imageURL = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
      this.showAlert(err);
    });
  }
```

Upload file (I am serving my Django project on my local PC with IP address 192.168.22.4):

```
transferData(auth){
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', auth);

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', this.imageURL, this.imageName);

      this.http.post("http://192.168.22.4/api-imageUpload", formData, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
        let status = res['status'];
        if(status == 200){
          this.showAlert( "The image was successfully uploaded!");
        }else{
          this.showAlert("upload error");
        }

      }, (err) => {
        var message = "Error in uploading file " + err
        this.showAlert(message);
      });  
  }
```

On Django, here is my serializer:

```
class ImageDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ImageDetails
        fields= ('image','status','category', 'user')   ####status, category has default value
```

and views.py:

```
class ImageDetailsViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ImageDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageDetailsSerializer
```

I am not sure if my code in uploading file is correct. I am trying to pass the data through Form data since the form works well in my API. Is this method correct? Are there any other methods to get this work?

Note: I have tried to use Transfer Cordova plugin but it is not working.

Comment: What's the content of the server's response ? 400 comes with a comprehensive message about what went wrong.

Comment: It says `400 Bad Request for URL` on ionic and `"POST /api-imageUpload HTTP/1.1" 400 85` on apache access log

Comment: none of which is the response body I asked. Open the developer tools and watch the server's response.

Comment: I am running it using an actual device and I don't know if it is possible the response using the device and I don't also know how to capture server response on Apache wamp & mod-wsgi aside from the apache error and access log.

Comment: which device ? android? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The HTTP 400 indicates that there is a syntax error somewhere in the code and that is the encoding used in the uploaded photo. Mobile data uses base64 encoding. When sending requests, the file will then be converted to a Unicode string.

On the other hand, Django-Rest uses normal encoding for images, thus by default, it cannot support base64 image. But luckily, this plugin is already available at [GitHub](https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields).

You just need to install the plugin and import it on your serializers.py:

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField
class ImageDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField()  
    class Meta:
        model = ImageDetails
        fields= ('image','status','category', 'user')
```

On Ionic side, you have to submit the actual image not the imageURL. In my case I just have to tweak my code to:

```
transferData(auth){

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', auth);

      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('category', 1);
      formData.append('status', 'Y')
      formData.append('image', this.imageName); 

      this.http.post("http://192.168.22.4/api-imageUpload", formData, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
        let status = res['status'];
        if(status == 201){
          var message = "The image was successfully uploaded!";
          this.showAlert(message);
        }else{
          var message = "upload error";
          this.showAlert(message);
        }

      }, (err) => {
        var message = "Error in uploading file " + err;
        this.showAlert(message);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to inspect what's ongoing with the request:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class ImageDetailsViewSet(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ImageDetails.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageDetailsSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        print(serializer.errors) # or better use logging if it's configured
        raise ValidationError(serialize.errors)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Hi. after trying the recommended answer, I still have the error. Here is a screen capture of my app: [![error.png](https://s21.postimg.org/hydq6vmjr/error.png)](https://postimg.org/image/6m14p3dur/)

Comment: I tried to edit my form data and added values to the columns that has default value, it then returns HTTP 500 with error message `{u'image': [u'The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.']}` error. After this, I have tried to append `'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` in the header and now its back to HTTP 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

Even without Base64 it is possible using ionic native components for file-transfer and image-picker see here: https://gist.github.com/AndreasDickow/9d5fcd2c608b4726d16dda37cc880a7b