# How to upload image to django 2.0 server via django-restframwork using Volley library in android?

Tags: android, python, django, django-rest-framework, android-volley

My goal is create an app like whatsapp or telegram (image only - no chats)
I want to send a picture to my Django server
this is my model:

```
class exchange(models.Model):
     sender=models.CharField(verbose_name="sender",max_length=11)
     reciever=models.CharField(verbose_name="reciever",max_length=11)
     img=models.ImageField(verbose_name="imageAddress",upload_to="image/")
     createTime=models.TimeField( auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

class users(models.Model):
     number=models.CharField(verbose_name="userNumber",max_length=11)
     name=models.CharField(verbose_name="name",max_length=40)
     createTime=models.TimeField( auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
     status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

class SMS(models.Model):
     users_id=models.ForeignKey(users,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
     code=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="randomCode")
     createTime=models.TimeField( auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
     status=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

exchange class ==> to store sender and receiver (phone number)
     img store image path on Django server .image store in    directory on server 
users class ==> for register users 
SMS class ==> for sms verificaion users like whatsup

My serializer API:

```
class exchangeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=exchange
        fields="__all__"


class SMSSerializer (ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models=SMS
        fields="__all__"

class usersSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=users
        fields="__all__"
```

my views API:

```
class exchangeShow(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset=exchange.objects.all()
    serializer_class=exchangeSerializer

class SMSShow(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset=SMS.objects.all()
    serializer_class=SMSSerializer

class usersShow(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset=users.objects.all()
    serializer_class=usersSerializer

class exchangeDetailShow(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset=exchange.objects.all()
    serializer_class=exchangeSerializer
    lookup_field='id'

class exchangeDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset=exchange.objects.all()
    serializer_class=exchangeSerializer
    lookup_field='id'

class exchangeCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=exchange.objects.all()
    serializer_class=exchangeSerializer

class SMSCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=SMS.objects.all();
    serializer_class=SMSSerializer;

class usersCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset=users.objects.all()
    serializer_class=usersSerializer
```

And URLs API:

```
urlpatterns=[
path('exchange/',views.exchangeShow.as_view()),
path('sms/',views.SMSShow.as_view()),
path('users/',views.usersShow.as_view()),
path('exchange/<int:id>/delete',views.exchangeDelete.as_view()),
path('exchange/create',views.exchangeCreate.as_view()),
path('sms/create',views.SMSCreate.as_view()),
path('users/create',views.usersCreate.as_view()),
]
```

In volley library 
how can I send image from Android device to Django and save it in a directory in server and store path it in exchange table (img) and show it in app in receiver

Comment: Send the image from android to Django via formdata. Change the model field img from Charfield to ImageField. So the Django Will save the name in DB and serve the Static files. You don't need to worry about anything.

Comment: If you need any code sample, revert me . I will add the code samples in answers

Comment: yes please add samples code

Comment: Check the First comment for image Save and serving from DRF. I don't have any idea for SMS verification

Comment: please explain   i am new in django  i created a model form and change img o ImageField

Comment: maybe this might help you? [Ionic 2 upload image to django rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782089/ionic-2-upload-image-to-django-rest/45588019#45588019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used HttpURLConnection instead of Volley

```
public class AsyncUpload extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
private String charset,url,path,num,nam;
private boolean type;

public  AsyncUpload(String url, String path,boolean type,String num,String nam){
     this.path= path;
     this.url = url;
     this.charset="UTF-8";
     this.type=type;
     this.num=num;
     this.nam=nam;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Sender multipart = null;
    String response;
    try {
        multipart = new Sender(url, path, charset);
        if (type)
         multipart.addFilePart();
         multipart.addFormField("number", num);
         multipart.addFormField("name", nam);
        response=multipart.finish();
         return response;
          } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR in AsyncUpload",e.toString() );
         return  "{\"success\":[]}";
    }
}}

public class connector {
public static HttpURLConnection connect(String surl,String b) {
    try {
       URL url=new URL(surl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    con.setReadTimeout(10000);
    con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+b);
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
    return con;
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}}


public class Sender {
private String url, path;
private String boundary = null;
private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
private String charset;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private PrintWriter writer;


public Sender( String url, String path, String charset) throws IOException {
    this.url = url;
    this.path = path;
    this.charset = charset;
    boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
    httpConn = connector.connect(url, boundary);
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
}

public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}


public void addFilePart()
        throws IOException {
    File uploadFile=new File(path);
    String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName)).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}
public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}
public String finish() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    writer.flush();
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }
    return response.toString();
}}
```