# Not able to upload images to Django Server using React Native app

Tags: android, django, react-native, axios, uri

I have a react native android app and a Django REST API. Using react-native-image-picker the user is able to select an image and the image successfully shows up in the react native app.

But then, I want to upload it to the API. For this, I am sending an axios request. When I send the request with image as **null** the request has a successful response. But, when the user selects an image then this request gives the following error:
**[Error: Request failed with status code 400]**

In the Django API, this image is defined as:
`image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/Images/Groups/', null=True)`

I know this is not the issue, because when I upload an image from the Django Administration, it successfully uploads the image as required.

And here is the API request to upload this image (and I know this is also not causing the issue):

```
const axios = require("axios");
   await axios.post('http://the url..., {
       //other fields I'm adding here
       "image": this.state.gImage,
   })
   .then((response) => {
       console.log(response);
   }, (error) => {
       console.log(error);
});
```

What I think the issue is, its in **uri** of the image that the user selects.
When the user selects the image from the phone's gallery, then the image
uri (which is in *this.state.gImage*) as displayed on the console is:

```
{"uri": "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F35531/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fpng/613917948"}
```

Does anyone have a solution? Or what could actually be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be something like this:

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('other-field', 'xyz');
form.append('image', {
        uri: pickerResponse.uri,
        name: pickerResponse.name,
        type: pickerResponse.type
    });

axios.post('url', form)
        .then(res => {
            //response
        }).catch(err=>{
            //error
        })
```

Comment: depending on picker library you use - uri, name and type response object can be different in which can you can use random name and expected type

Comment: Thanks I tried this, and now it does not give that 400 error but now it shows this Network Error: **[Error: Network Error]** Do you know what could be causing the issue now?

Comment: Can't say for sure. Try using postman and see if it give some server related error or try logging the error response to see what message the server returns

Comment: Thanks for helping! I searched for this and now the issue is solved. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42820459/10000229) helped. Actually the image I was uploading was base64 encoded and Django REST does not support it by default. So, I followed the steps in the given link and the image upload was successful.